# javascript: replace last value with number of positive values in an array

Tags: javascript, html

In an array,  replace last value with number of positive values.

for example, arr[-1,-5,-5,10] changes into [-1,-5,-5,1] and print it.(since 10 is the only positive number in the array).

I am stuck on how to replace the last value with the count of positive numbers in an array. Hope anyone can help me, Thanks in advance.

```js
// Enter code below
var arr = [-1,-5,-5,10];
//var numList=[];
//var newValue = null;
var positiveNum = null;

for (let i =0; i< arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i]> 0){
      positiveNum++;
      let lastElement = arr[arr.length - 1];
      lastElementValue = positiveNum;
      
    }
 
 }
     console.log(arr,lastElementValue);// This is wrong, but the closest I can get
```

```js
var arr = [-1,-5,-5,10];
var numList=[];
var positiveNum = null;

for (let i =0; i< arr.length; i++){
    if (arr[i]< 0){
      positiveNum++;
    }
    else{
      numList.push(arr[i]);
    }
    
 }
     //arr[arr.length - 1] = positiveNum;
     //numList.push(arr[arr.length - 1] );
     console.log(numList); // I only able to print the positive number here
```

Comment: In the first snippet `arr[arr.length - 1] = positiveNum` should work, see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: You can also use a "modern" javascript one-liner: `arr.splice(-1, 1, arr.filter(x=>x>0).length);` with the result in the changed `arr`: `console.log(arr)`

Answer (score 3):

You can do like this:

```js
const helper = (arr) => {
  let count = 0;

  for (const number of arr) {
    if (number > 0) {
      count += 1;
    }
  }

  arr[arr.length - 1] = count;
  return arr;
};

console.log(helper([-1, -5, -5, 10]));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
// Enter code below
var arr = [-1,-5,-5,10];
var positiveNum = 0;

for (let i =0; i< arr.length; i++){
    arr[i]> 0 ? positiveNum++ : '';
    i == arr.length-1 ? arr[i] = positiveNum : '';
 }
     console.log(arr);
```